# Modal popup menu on scene in sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, modal-dialog, sprite-kit

I would like to have modal popup menu appearing on the top of my scene.

How can I do it with SpriteKit and objective-c? Scene should be paused before popup showed and restored after popup closed.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Add new sprite and set z position.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to pause the SKView:

`SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
    view.paused = YES;`

Then create a new object/sprite/image that is your popup menu, or add the specified buttons.
Bring it to the front using `popupMenu.zPosition = 2;` (This assumes all other objects are zPosition 1 or lower)

Once the user has chosen an option, handle the event then un-pause the view with the same code we used to pause it, just change `YES` to `NO`.